# Checking a String value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I would like to incorporate into SQL an if statement determining if the value of a string is equal to "" (and I don't mean an empty string - I mean a string of two quotation marks). How can I do this. I would like the SQL to look something like this:

```
Select iif(Answer="","No Response", Answer)
From tblAnswers
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're using Microsoft Access (judging by the use of iif). To escape double quotes, you should be able to do:

```
Select iif(Answer = """""", "No Response", Answer)
From tblAnswers
```

Comment: Thank you for reading into the iif statement and realizing what I forgot to mention - that I am using MS Access. Works Perfectly!

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN Answer = '""' THEN 'No Response'
       ELSE Answer
       END AS Answer
  FROM tblAnswers
```

Comment: @Bohemian - I wouldn't be so sure. iif is a dead giveaway of Microsoft Access which doesn't support full SQL. Don't know if it will allow CASE statements.

Comment: It definitely will NOT work with Access, since Access/Jet/ACE SQL has no SELECT CASE. But testing against `'""'` definitely WILL work. How a user inputs two double quotes using Access, I don't know -- when I try it Access, I get an error that shows it interprets entry of `""` as an attempt to store a zero-length string (which I never allow in any of my fields).

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server:

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(Answer, ""), "No Response")
```

Comment: This is incorrect. OP said string will be 2 quotation marks, not empty.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

`SELECT CASE WHEN Answer = '' THEN 'No Response' ELSE Answer END FROM tblAnswers`

Comment: Not applicable to Access/Jet/ACE, but the OP didn't indicate the database engine.

Answer (score 2):

Access' database engine will recognize string literals enclosed in either single or double quotes.  So although this one will work ...

```
Select IIf(Answer = """""", "No Response", Answer)
From tblAnswers;
```

... single quotes would make it clearer, IMO, and I'd be less likely to lose track of the proper number of double quotes when my eyes are tired.  So I'd do this instead ...

```
Select IIf(Answer = '""', 'No Response', Answer)
From tblAnswers;
```

If you also want to output *No Response* when Answer is Null or an empty string, try this ...

```
Select IIf(Answer = '""' OR Len(Answer & "") = 0, 'No Response', Answer)
From tblAnswers;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an escape character.  In SQL I believe it would be

```
Answer = "\"\"";
```

Comment: Not applicable to Access/Jet/ACE, but the OP didn't indicate the database engine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select if(Answer='""', 'No Response', Answer) as Answer
From tblAnswers
```

The exact syntax will vary with your actual database. You may need a `CASE` if your DB doesn't support `if`

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle

```
select decode(answer,"''''","No response",answer) from tblanswers
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(Answer,'""'), 'No Response') Answer
FROM tblAnswers
```

If the column contains two single quotes, use this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULLIF(Answer, ''''), 'No Response') Answer
FROM tblAnswers
```

Comment: Not applicable to Access/Jet/ACE, but the OP didn't indicate the database engine.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IIF(Answer = CHAR(34) & CHAR(34), 'No Response', Answer)
  FROM tblAnswers;
```